# Retrieve element's key in React

Tags: reactjs

In a React component I've created, I have this inside the `render` method return value:

```
this.props.albums.map(function(albumDetails, id) {
    return (<div className="artistDetail" key={id} onClick={component.getTracks}>
        <img src={albumDetails.imageSrc} />
        <p><a href="#" >{albumDetails.name}</a></p>
    </div>)
```

If I didn't specify a key, React warned me to do so. So I did. I then specified `onClick` event handler:

```
getTracks: function (e) {
   console.log(e.target.key);
},
```

in hope I can get the  `<div>` key attribute I created. This does not work, however (I get some HTML output for `e.target` but nothing for `e.target.key`). How can I get the `key` attribute off an element that I've clicked on?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The best way to get the key attribute value that you set is to just pass it as another attribute as well that has meaning. For example, I often do this:

```
const userListItems = users.map(user => {
  return <UserListItem
    key={ user.id }
    id={ user.id }
    name={ user.name }
  });
```

or in your case:

```
this.props.albums.map(function(albumDetails) {
  return (<div className="artistDetail" key={albumDetails.id} data-id={ albumDetails.id } onClick={component.getTracks}>
      <img src={albumDetails.imageSrc} />
      <p><a href="#" >{albumDetails.name}</a></p>
  </div>)
```

It seems redundant, but I think its more explicit because `key` is a purely react implementation concept, which could mean something different than `id`, even though I almost always use unique IDs as my `key` values. If you want to have `id` when you reference the object, just pass it in.

Comment: What's the point of having "key" as an internal react implementation? Do all elements in the app need to have different keys or just elements within the scope of map()?

Comment: The `key` attribute is used by react to ensure that dom elements correspond with data objects. You can read more about dynamic children in react here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html

Answer (score 0):

The key is for React's internal use and won't display in the HTML and Console, you just have to use the id to retrieve that unique component.
eg:

```
getTracks: function (e) {
   console.log(e.target.id?e.target.id:e.target);
}
```

```
this.props.albums.map(function(albumDetails) {
  return (<div key id={ albumDetails.id } onClick={component.getTracks} className="artistDetail" >
      <img src={albumDetails.imageSrc} />
      <p><a href="#" >{albumDetails.name}</a></p>
  </div>)
}
```

And also you don't need to pass value to the key attribute.Value is completely optional.